# vb.net use linq to sort collection of structures by two fields

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting

I have a large collection (Me.OmniColl) of the same structure. Two properties of the structure are .partNumber and .rev. I want to sort first by the part number and then by the rev.

I have tried the following:

```
Dim q = From c In Me.OmniColl Order By c.partNumber Select c
Dim r = From c In q Order By c.rev Select c
```

Neither q nor r return any results, even though Me.OmniColl contains thousands of entries. I am already using linq to filter the collection successfully, but all of my sorting attempts have failed. If anyone has a solution, please show your code in vb.net. Thanks in advance for your help.

[Edit]
The structure:

```
<Serializable()> Structure Part  
    Public Workbook As String
    Public Worksheet As String
    Public Product As String
    Public partNumber As String
    Public itemNo As String
    Public rev As String
    Public partDescription As String
    Public unitOfMeasure As String
    Public partType As String
    Public purchasingCat As String
    Public Quantity As Double
    Public TotalPerProduct As Double
    Public hierarchy As String
End Structure
```

[Edit]
I want to find a solution without changing from a Collection to some other type and without changing from a Structure to a Public Class. I have a data caching system in place where I serialize the collection of structures and save this in a textfile before closing the program. I then de-serialize this textfile on program opening and edit the collection as needed based on whether changes to the files the collection is generated from have been made. Sorry for making so many edits.

Comment: Can you show the structure?

Comment: What are the properties of your collection update it to post

Comment: Well worth reading [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx)...and yeah, what the collection is since this is VB

Comment: Was it the `VisualBasic.Collection` before?  the question has now changed again, and hitting a moving target online is problematic.  So, use a Class, a List(of T) and turn on Option Strict `Dim q = From c In col Order By c.partNumber, c.rev Select c`

Comment: @Plutonix just nitpicking ; the `Select c` part can be omitted as `c` is the only query variable in scope

Comment: @Sehnsucht yes - that was an edit and time was running out - just pasted the OP's query

Comment: I populate the Collection of Part structures, by de-serializing a textfile. I have searched for ways of de-serializing the file into a List(Of T), but I have had no luck. Is there any way I can stick with a collection of structs and still sort?

Comment: Connor, do not use structures over 16 bytes. This is bad bad bad. Eject - use class. Always remember how memory management works and what type of object structure represents

Comment: Have you tried this? `list.OrderBy(o => o.PartNumber, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ThenBy(o => o.Rev).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Generic.List(Of Part)` in my opinion. In my example below `col` is a `Generic.List(Of Part)` defined at the top of my class, replace it with your's. Mine looked like this:

```
 Dim col As New Generic.List(Of Part)
```

To get your `List` ordered...

```
 Dim newCol As Generic.List(Of Part) = (From c In col Order By c.partNumber, c.rev).ToList()
```

This will order your item's as needed. Then you asked about removing specific items.

You can use the `ForEach` function which perform's specific action on each element in the list

```
 newCol.ForEach(Sub(x)
                       If x.Workbook = condition Then
                           newCol.Remove(x)
                       End If
                End Sub)
```

**Note: This has been tried and tested**

**Edit:**

If you want to get your `Collection` into a `List`...

```
 Dim newColl As List(Of Part) = YOURCOLLECTION.Cast(Of Part).ToList
```